# LibSVM fails (SEGFAULT) on large feature vector

Tags: libsvm, c++

I'm building an NDK app for Android that uses LibSVM. I've built an equivalent for my mac in XCode (both C++)

I find that the Mac can handle the extremely large feature vector I give it with high speed and accuracy (~16800 features) for training and classiifcation

On Android (very similar code) I can successfuly train/learn on 150 features but I get the following segfault when I try my full 16800 features (even though it works great on Mac). Only with classification (`svm_predict` though. Training always works fine.

You can see it fails on the "dot" function used by LibSVM

```
0-16 23:28:41.084 30997-31028/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xaf000000 in tid 31028 (GLThread 17147)
10-16 23:28:41.190 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-16 23:28:41.191 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:5.1.1/LMY48M/2167285:user/release-keys'
10-16 23:28:41.191 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '11'
10-16 23:28:41.191 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
10-16 23:28:41.191 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG: pid: 30997, tid: 31028, name: GLThread 17147  >>> cc.openframeworks.androidEmptyExample <<<
10-16 23:28:41.191 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xaf000000
10-16 23:28:41.202 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG:     r0 aef3e000  r1 aef5ed10  r2 00000001  r3 af000000
10-16 23:28:41.202 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG:     r4 aec29eb8  r5 00000001  r6 b4b2c608  r7 12d090c0
10-16 23:28:41.202 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG:     r8 12d15660  r9 b4a39400  sl 00000000  fp af37d824
10-16 23:28:41.202 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG:     ip b6e417dc  sp af37d810  lr a301ff78  pc a301ff04  cpsr 000f0010
10-16 23:28:41.202 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00167f04  /data/app/cc.openframeworks.androidEmptyExample-1/lib/arm/libOFAndroidApp.so (Kernel::dot(svm_node const*, svm_node const*)+192)
```

Any ideas as to what is going on here?

I'm using the following parameters:

```
  mSvm.setSvmType(C_SVC);
  mSvm.setKernelType(LINEAR);
  mSvm.setCost(1);
  mSvm.setGamma(1/16800);
  mSvm.setCoef0(0);
  mSvm.setCachesize(40);
  mSvm.setEpsilon(0.001);
  mSvm.setShrinking(false);

  mSvm.setDegree(1);
  mSvm.setNu(0.5);
```

Comment: Can you compile with a `g` flag and run under valgrind?  That will help you spot memory leaks and invalid pointers.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're getting the error from LIBSVM's dot product operation based on the following line:

> 10-16 23:28:41.202 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00167f04  /data/app/cc.openframeworks.androidEmptyExample-1/lib/arm/libOFAndroidApp.so (Kernel::dot(svm_node const*, svm_node const*)+192)

This routine is tested insanely often by a very large number of users, so I am skeptical that the error is in there.

Are you 100% sure that your pointers are valid? Is there a possibility that you just happen to get lucky with undefined behaviour on the mac version? What I mean is, is it possible that the pointers you are providing are consistently invalid on all platforms, but just happen to still work on the mac version? Such errors that give the illusion of working properly are not uncommon when you work on multiple platforms.

Comment: Here's the source if it helps: https://github.com/arnaudsj/libsvm/blob/master/svm.cpp#L293.

Comment: It's possible that the pointers are invalid -- I'm using multiple threads to do the learning in the background while a visualization is going on. I'm using this library to interface with my code: https://github.com/TatsuyaOGth/ofxSvm

I can successfully `addData()` and `train()` but it seems my `mModel` or `node` in the `predict(vector<double>)` is throwing off the dot product. I suspect my model var is being disposed of somehow -- any ideas from looking at the above wrapper if there are any obvious bugs/possible conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in 'dot' function, and I solved by not including '0' as a value of the svm_nodes. The function is expecting an index of '-1' and a value of '0' to mark the end of the list of svm_nodes (training vector).

For sure it is a bit late for you but hopefully it will help future libsvm users :)